# Access denied during monitor driver update

Tags: drivers, display, multiple-monitors, display-driver, software-update

I have monitor IIYAMA PROLITE XUB2790HS-B1.
When I want to update software (downloaded from IIYAMA site) I got below error:

[image]

How to update drivers? (like manually copy?)

Comment: Why do you want to update your monitor's drivers in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the driver were are into "Read Only" and it was root cause.

I moved to USB flash disk and update once again and it run successful.